# laravel inner join with another column name

Tags: laravel

```
        $data['sidebarComments'] = Comment::join('articles', 'articles.id', '=', 'comments.article_id' )->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'articles.category_id')->get();
```

This is my code. I'm combining 3 tables. First table is comment, second table is articles, third table is categories.  But in my articles table there is a slug column. Also in my categories table there is  a slug column. So its mixing, and the code is taking last slug column. But i wanna take 2 columns. How to change the column name with inner join? If you help me i will be glad.

Comment: Is there a reason, you don't work with [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [select statement](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#select-statements).

```
$data['sidebarComments'] = Comment::join('articles', 'articles.id', '=', 'comments.article_id' )
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'articles.category_id')
    ->select([
        // all fields that you want to select
        "articles.slug as articlesSlug",
        "categories.slug as categoriesSlug"
    ])
    ->get();
```